# Simulate button click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I wanted to create a simple auto-skip with Greasemonkey, but I found that no solution found on Stack Overflow actually works for me.

I need to click this button:

```
<div tip="next" title="Next" class="linkable fa fa-arrow-right" ng-click="View.next()"></div>
```

It doesn't have any id nor name and is hidden deep inside many divs. I could bypass the click wiht simulating enter or right arrow press, but that also didn't work for me.

Comment: why does this button does not have any id or name?

Comment: when you click the button an event is triggered and a function is called ? just call directly the function don't spend your time.

Comment: @SaschaP Don't know. It's not my site that's why I wanted to create a script with GreaseMoneky :-)

Comment: @SaschaP It's not his code, and elements don't need to have an id, class or name. at: Anon The function might be scoped, so greasemonkey might not be able to run that function.

Comment: @Anonymous0day Actually I don't know. I tried to call Vie.next(), but it did nothing

Comment: What you can try is to find the parent element and then select the first child -> the div. Can you post more of the HTML?

Comment: ah, I see... are there any other elements with the classes `linkable`, `fa` or `fa-arrow-right`? You could probably use `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[index_of_button]`

Comment: maybe something like that :  `document.querySelector('div.linkable.fa.fa-arrow-right[ng-click="View.next()"]'`

Comment: @DaveChen the site is [BetterFap](http://betterfap.com/view/6517932). It's easier if you look at yourself.

Comment: Where is button? I am only seeing block level element!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('div[tip="next"]').click()
```

From what I saw these GreaseMonkey scripts run on page load. Using this I was able to simulate the click.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   blargtest
// @include     https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
setTimeout(
    function () {
        document.querySelector('div[tip="next"]').click();
    }, 1000
);
```

You could make that a setInterval and have it click next every second.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/iLSPcZfh) is my test script and it doesn't seem to work :-(

Comment: I am not familiar with GreaseMonkey scripting but if you run the line of code I put above in the browser console it works. Let me take a look at grease monkey and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Yep, you're right it works in console, will try to play with it :)

Comment: @MarekLukáš Have you made sure that the DOM is loaded and the `div` exists before clicking it? Try surrounding that line with a `try-catch` block and use `console.log` to debug that line.

Comment: It seems these scripts run on the load of page. When I did this it seemed to work.  setTimeout(function () {
document.querySelector('div[tip="next"]').click();
}, 1000);

Comment: @MarekLukáš Should be obvious… `document.querySelector('div.linkable.fa.fa-arrow-right[ng-click='View.next() ']')` is a syntax error.

Comment: @MarekLukáš I updated my answer with more.

Comment: Finally! I made it to work by using setTimeout

Comment: Great to hear. If you felt my answer was useful to you would mind accepting it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @MarekLukáš Did you fix the syntax error?

Comment: works for me! thanks

Comment: @CarlosCarrizales glad it helped!! =]